# Field for if the current user is a member of the organic group

Tags: organic-groups, services

I am working with [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) to create an API. I have created a View that shows list of Organic groups.

Now I need to add a field which will show if the current user is member of the group or not. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you using [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) to retrieve your view from your REST API?

Comment: @ShawnConn Yes, I am using Services Views

Answer (score 1):

There is no field or direct method to show "If the current user is member of the group or not". In your case I have found a solution here:

1. Create a view - showing list of all groups(you have already created).
2. Add new Relationship - **OG membership: OG membership from Node group**
3. Add new field - **(OG membership from node group) OG membership: Group ID (Group ID)**, you can exclude it from display.
4. Add new field - **Global: PHP** (you have to enable [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module for this field) and put below code in this field:

   ```
   <?php

   global $user;
   $account = user_load($user->uid);
   $ugrpid = $account->og_user_node['und'][0]['target_id'];

   if($row->gid == $ugrpid){
     echo "Already Subscribed.";
   }else{
     echo "Not member of this Group.";
   }

   ?>
   ```

This is how my view look like( Screenshot ).

[image]

Comment: Its not working. I followed your instructions. When I look at the auto preview under the view it always says "Not member of this group". And when I get URL using RESTclient, there is no output.

Here is screenshot of View : http://i66.tinypic.com/2dak27q.jpg
Here is screenshot of RESTclient : http://i65.tinypic.com/2cpccgl.png

Comment: Please check the Screenshot added.

Comment: In the relationship, where you have "OG membership from Node group", I don't have this option.. I got this option "OG membership from Content group" ? Please suggest what I should do ?